# Extended cyclotomic criterion for unitary categorification

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, subfactors, fusion-categories, cyclotomic-fields, unitary-fusion-category

According to [this paper](https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2005.162.581) (Corollary 8.54) the Frobenius-Perron dimension (FPdim) of any object $a$ of a fusion category over $\mathbb{C}$ is a cyclotomic integer. Now, FPdim($a$) is the maximal eigenvalue of the fusion matrix $M_a$ of $a$, and by applying Theorem 8.51, for a unitary fusion category, if the Grothendieck ring is commutative, all the eigenvalues of every fusion matrix are cyclotomic integers. That is why the character table of a finite group has cyclotomic integer entries. But what about the non-commutative case? It is true for the (Extended-)Haagerup fusion categories H6 and EH8. Next, what about the non-unitary case? Let focus on the unitary case:

A cyclotomic field is an abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and by [Kronecker–Weber theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem), every finite abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subfield of a cyclotomic field.

It follows that for the commutative fusion rings, the cyclotomic criterion extends, for unitary categorification, as follows:

> The Galois group of the characteristic polynomial of every fusion
> matrix must be abelian.

**Question**: Is the above also a criterion for the noncommutative fusion rings?

IOW: Are all the eigenvalues of every fusion matrix of a unitary fusion category also cyclotomic integers if the Grothendieck ring is noncommutative?

*Bonus question*: Is it true in the non-unitary case?

---

To show that the extended cyclotomic criterion is relevant and not only for non-integral fusion ring, let mention here an example of (perfect) integral commutative fusion ring which can be ruled out from unitary categorification by this criterion exclusively (according to my current knowledge).
It has rank $8$, FPdim $1260$, type $[[1, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [5, 1], [20, 3]]$ and fusion rules:
$$
\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\end{smallmatrix} , \ \begin{smallmatrix}0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&3&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&3&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&3\end{smallmatrix} , \ \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 1&0&1&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&3&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&3&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&3\end{smallmatrix} , \ \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&1&2&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&4&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&4&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&4\end{smallmatrix},$$
$$\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&1&1&2&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&1&2&2&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&5&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&5&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&5\end{smallmatrix} , \ \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&3&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&3&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&4&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&5&0&0 \\ 1&3&3&4&5&4&3&10 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&3&8&9 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&10&9&1\end{smallmatrix} , \ \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&3&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&3&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&4&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&5&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&3&8&9 \\ 1&3&3&4&5&8&4&5 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&9&5&6\end{smallmatrix} , \ \begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&3 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&3 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&4 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&5 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&10&9&1 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&9&5&6 \\ 1&3&3&4&5&1&6&10\end{smallmatrix}
$$
(it admits the Grothendieck ring of Rep$(A_5)$ as fusion subring)

Now, the 6th fusion matrix above $$M= \left(  \begin{matrix}0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&3&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&3&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&4&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&5&0&0 \\ 1&3&3&4&5&4&3&10 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&3&8&9 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&10&9&1\end{matrix} \right)$$
admits the characteristic polynomial $$\chi_M(x) = x^4(x^4 - 13x^3 - 206x^2 + 1101x + 4380)$$
whose Galois group is $S_3$ (non-abelian).